# legacy bootstrap 2.3.2 clearing row when generating multiple spans

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I clear rows in bootstrap 2.3.2 when generating `span4` dynamically for thumbnail photos?

```
$.each(data.photos, function(index, value) {
        $('#photo').append(
            '<div class="span4"> <img src="./assets/imgs/' + value.image + '" alt="..." class="img-rounded"> </div>'
enter code here
        );

<div class="row-fluid auto-clear">
   <div id="photo"></div>
 </div>
```

tried this css but no luck

```
@media (min-width:1200px){
    .auto-clear .span1:nth-child(12n+1){clear:left;}
    .auto-clear .span2:nth-child(6n+1){clear:left;}
    .auto-clear .span3:nth-child(4n+1){clear:left;}
    .auto-clear .span4:nth-child(3n+1){clear:left;}
    .auto-clear .span6:nth-child(odd){clear:left;}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you could add a count so every 3 item it outputted you could add a new div to the code:

```
var i = 0;
$.each(data.photos, function(index, value) {
    if(i == 3) {
       $('#photo').append('<div class="clearfix"></div>');
       i = 0;
    }
    $('#photo')
        .append('<div class="span4"> <img src="./assets/imgs/' + value.image + '" alt="..." class="img-rounded"> </div>');
    }
 i++;
}
```

Comment: But then you'll have to repeat the same step if you're rendering `span3` and have to change `i == 4`?

Comment: so are you going to be generating the span element for this based on the size of the screen. I mentioned this way as your only using span4 in your example.

Comment: Was hoping if there's a way of clearing the row in CSS, I know bootstrap 3.x have some css way of clearing it.

Comment: is upgrading the bootstrap not an option?
or
you could look at flexbox to achieve this.